# Xcode can't import PDF asset

Tags: xcode

Since Xcode6 can use vector assets, our designer starts to export PDF format assets instead of PNG. this's very very convenience but I found that I can't import PDF through "import action" by right click, see the PDF files is unavailable state with gray color:

[image]

[image]

And I can import it by dragging it directly.

Is there anything I am wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following link, it might be of help : http://martiancraft.com/blog/2014/09/vector-images-xcode6/